# Is $f_{n}(x)=g(x^{n})$ uniformly convergent on $[1,\infty)$ and $[c,\infty)$ where $c>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_{n}(x)=g(x^{n})$ where $g(x)=\ln(x)/(1+x)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x\in [1,\infty)$.

> <s>i) Show that the convergence is not uniform. Hint: Consider for example
> $f_{n}(2^{1/n})$</s>.
>
> ii) Let $c>1$. Show that the convergence is uniform for $x\in [c,\infty)$.

Define $$d_{A}(f,f_{n}):=\sup_{x\in A}\left \{ \left | f(x)-f_{n}(x) \right | \right \}.$$

i) **EDIT**: Solved.

ii) Note that for all $x\geq 1$, $$g'(x)=\frac{1/x+1-\ln(x)}{(1+x)^{2}}\leq \frac{2-\ln(x)}{(1+x^{2})}$$
then $g(x)$ is decreaing if $\ln(x)\geq 2$. Let $n\geq 1$. So $f_{n}(x)$ is decreasing if $\ln(x^{n})\geq 2$. Since $x\geq c$, then $\ln(c^{n})\geq \ln(x^{n})\geq 2$. It gives me an idea to prove it. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N\geq 2\ln(c)$. Then $d_{[c,\infty)}(f,f_{n})<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{[c,\infty)}(f,f_{n})= 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Why you did not use the hint? To prove that something do not converge uniformly it is no useful to find a bound for above.

Comment: @YotasTrejos Why isn't it useful? I'd love to know it. In order to use the hint, I would get $0<f(2^{1/n})=g(2)$ and $g(2)\leq d_{[1,\infty)}(f,f_{n})$, then it imples that $0<d_{[1,\infty)}(f,f_{n})$ which shows that it can not go to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. But I don't feel that this hint seems convincing. I want to do it something general.

Comment: Draw the graph of $g$ and try to understand what the transformation $x\mapsto x^2$ does to this graph. This is really important to understand why this sequence cannot be uniformly convergent.

Comment: But proving that some function do not converge uniformly you need to find a particular sequence of numbers, there is not general way, maybe if you find each sequence that do not converge at the same "rhythm".

Comment: It is not useful because you need to bound the function for below.

Comment: @YotasTrejos You are saying, that if I want to show that it's uniformly convergent, then I have to find a bound for above. And if I want to show that it's not uniformly convergent, then I have to find a bound for below. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, you do. But it is not just a bound for above but a bound for above that tends to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Where do you use the hypothesis that $c>1$ in ii. ?

Comment: Well, I guess I use this hypothesis before this part, "Since $x\geq c$". I didn't know if it does some difference if I didn't mention "Let $c>1$" when it already is let in the problem.

Comment: You suppose that $x\geq c$ and conclude that $\log c^n \geq \log x^n$ this is not true. The $\log$ function is increasing.

Comment: You are right. It should be $\ln(x^{n})\geq \ln(c^{n})$. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this sequence as
$$f_n(x)=\displaystyle\frac{n\log x}{1+x^n}$$
To get a bound see that ($x\geq c>1$)
$$\displaystyle\frac{n\log x}{1+x^n}\leq\displaystyle\frac{n(1+x)}{1+x^n}$$ 
Since $\log x<l+1$ if $x\geq 1$. Now convince yourself that the function
$$\displaystyle\frac{n(1+x)}{1+x^n}$$
Is decreasing if $n\geq 2$ and $x>1$. We can get the correct bound
$$\displaystyle\frac{n(1+x)}{1+x^n}\leq\displaystyle\frac{n(1+c)}{1+c^n}$$
This clearly implies
$$\displaystyle\frac{n\log x}{1+x^n}\leq\displaystyle\frac{n(1+c)}{1+c^n}$$
Take $n\rightarrow \infty$ to get the result.